# How can I perform ETL on a Spark Row and return it to a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I'm currently using Scala Spark for some ETL and have a base dataframe that contains has the following schema

```
|-- round: string (nullable = true)
|-- Id : string (nullable = true)
|-- questions: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- tag: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- bonusQuestions: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- difficulty : string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- answerOptions: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- followUpAnswers: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- school: string (nullable = true)
```

I only need to perform ETL on rows where the `round` type is `primary` (there are 2 types primary and secondary). However, I need both type of rows in my final table.

I'm stuck doing the ETL which should be according to - 
If tag is non-bonus, the `bonusQuestions` should be set to `null` and `difficulty` should be `null`.

I'm currently able to access most fields of the DF like
`val round =  tr.getAs[String]("round")`

Next, I'm able to get the questions array using

`val questionsArray = tr.getAs[Seq[StructType]]("questions")`

and can iterate using `for (question <- questionsArray) {...}`; However I cannot access struct fields like `question.bonusQuestions` or `question.tag`which returns an error

```
error: value tag is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
```

Comment: its already in rdd so instead of `question.bonusQuestions` you have to do `question.getSeq("bonusQuestions")` and instead of `question.tag` you have to do `question.getString("tag")`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan that gives me the same error 
`value getString is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan tr is just a Row of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark treats `StructType` as `GenericRowWithSchema`, more specific as `Row`. So instead of `Seq[StructType]` you have to use `Seq[Row]` as

```
val questionsArray = tr.getAs[Seq[Row]]("questions")
```

and in the loop `for (question <- questionsArray) {...}` you can get the data of `Row` as

```
for (question <- questionsArray) {
    val tag = question.getAs[String]("tag")
    val bonusQuestions = question.getAs[Seq[String]]("bonusQuestions")
    val difficulty = question.getAs[String]("difficulty")
    val answerOptions = question.getAs[Seq[String]]("answerOptions")
    val followUpAnswers = question.getAs[Seq[String]]("followUpAnswers")
  }
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks Ramesh! This was super helpful.